# Angular 2 quickstart for visual studio 2015: Angular can't find app.module

Tags: visual-studio, angular

I have been trying to get the Angular quickstart to work using visual studio 2015.
I have been following the step by step tutorial on the angular.io website
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html.
When I first ran the application I received a some `404` when a request was fired for `systemjs.config.js` and `System.import('main.js')`.
After changing these path by prefixing them with `src/` those issues were resolved but now I still get another `404` on the `/src/app/app.module`.

Looking in the main.ts file located in the `src` folder I see the following path:

`import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';`

That is exactly were the app.module is located, so why is it still giving a 404?

Comment: `main.ts` should be within the same location as `app.module.ts`, so your reference should be `./app.module`. If main.ts is within the parent directory then ensure your TypeScript version in VS is up to date - this can cause very large problems.

Comment: I have downloaded and extracted the quickstart.zip from the angular.io website and by default the main.ts file is in the 'src' folder and the app.module.ts in the src/app folder. I haven't moved any files.
When I move main.ts to the same folder as app.module.ts I still get the same 404.
The funny thing is that when I change the reference in main.ts to opp.module Visual Studio immediately tells me the path is wrong.

I had already updated Typescript.

Comment: What's the full requested location for app.module? You should see it in your developer tools Network tab.

Comment: http://localhost:55303/src/app/app.module that is the requested path for the file. Weird thing is, is that Windows 10 seems to think this is a video file, it opens the mediaplayer when I download the file.

Comment: I don't think `src` is meant to be part of your development environment - by that I mean the files such as `tsconfig` and `system.js` should be in the root of your project. I would delete the files you extracted then extract a fresh copy of everything from the `src` folder.

Comment: That doesn't work either, it still can't find app.module.

Comment: I eventually got this to work by moving the entire node_modules folder one level up, Probable not the way to go for a production environment but given the fact that this was entirely for testing purposes this solved my problem.
It does seem strange that the guide mentioned above doesn't seem to work without deviating from the guide.